# How to hide requests from a client react js website

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have a `C#` server side web service. but I don't want user can to see my requests like request tab from client's browsers.

now, I haven't been find any solution on SO.
what is the best solution to do this?

I think I can use a `node.js` server-side and render my `reactjs` inside it and my `node.js` send my requests to `C#` server side. like this:

```
React.js<--(render)--Node.js--(Send/Receive api's)-->C#
```

I don't know if I use a `node.js` server, my requests will be hidden from clients?

I don't want to use `reactjs.net`.

Comment: In my opinion its a bit of an overkill. Is there a special reason why you don't want your users to be able to view the requests. There are other good methods to hide information

Comment: The user shouldn't be able to see the requests made by node to your c# backend. Is there a specific set of requests or specific information you are trying to hide? The requests made by the browser (react) to node is shown in the request tabs.

Comment: @Alex my data is critical data. I don't want to send request to node.js. I want to node.js render my react. is it possible?

Comment: how about bundling your react code into a single file, put the bundle file and all the html and css into a cloud storage provider or firebase and serve it from there?

Comment: What's the point here? They are still going to see 1) the initial request to the Node server, and 2) response from the Node server that contains the data pulled from the C# request. They can still fire off the request to node and see the resulting API data.

Comment: @S.M_Emamian , you want node to render your react?  I mean you certainely can have a node server return react components to the client but I don't see how this is providing the solution you want.  Assuming you're gonna use https, is there any data you want the user to have but not want them to see? I'm confused...  Using https would prevent other people aside from the actual user from seeing the data

Answer (score 1):

If you're making a HTTP request to node server, and making the stealth request from NodeJS to another server, that request will not be visible to the client.

Alternatively, you can make an encrypted request. Although URL and some part of encryption algorithm will still be exposed at client's end.